# mapear tabla cuya PK es la union de dos tablas

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo el siguiente esquema de bbdd y lo quiero mapear en java con hibernate y JPA:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué anotaciones deberían llevar cada una de las 3 entidades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Entity //Nombre de la entidad en java
@Table(name = "SP_ESPECIALIDAD") //Nombre de la tabla en la bd
public class SP_ESPECIALIDAD implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id //Declara una columna en la bd como la llave primaria
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) //Tipo de incremento: sequence, identity, auto_increment
    @Column(name = "cod_esp") //Nombre de la columna de la tabla en la bd
    private int cod_esp;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sp_especialidad") //Sirve para relacionar de manera bidireccional (contiene el detalle)
    private List<SP_ESPECIALIDAD_PROV> listaPorEspecialidad;

    //Getters & Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PROVEEDOR")
public class PROVEEDOR implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "cod_proveedor")
    private int cod_proveedor;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proveedor")
    private List<SP_ESPECIALIDAD_PROV> listaPorProveedor;

    //Getters & Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SP_ESPECIALIDAD_PROV")
public class SP_ESPECIALIDAD_PROV implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "cod_proveedor")
    private int id_espec_prov;

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "cod_esp", nullable = false) //Con esta anotación declaras llave foránea y el nombre del campo "sp_especialidad" servirá para mapear de manera inversa como viste en la primera clase llamada SP_ESPECIALIDAD
    private SP_ESPECIALIDAD sp_especialidad;

   @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "cod_proveedor", nullable = false)
    private SP_ESPECIALIDAD proveedor;

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

Comment: Añadiendo la anotación @JoinColumn en vez de mappedBy?

Comment: @JoinColumn sirve para crear la llave foránea en la tabla.
mappedBy es la relación inversa. Y es opcional, en el caso que desees listar el detalle desde la clase que contiene la llave primaria.

Comment: Me surge unan duda, si la tabla SP_ESPECIALDIAD tuviese COD_ESP como UK y no como Primary key, cómo se realizaría el mapeo de entidades?se le añadiría la anotación '@Column' y junto a la anotación de '@Table' '@UniqueConstraint' (columnNames="COD_ESP")?